# Keras earlystopping: print selected epoch

Tags: python, callback, keras

Simple question. I am using Keras earlystopping in the following form:

```
Earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')
```

How can I get Keras to print the selected epoch once the model has been fit? I think you have to use logs but don't quite know how.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

The full code is very long! Let me add a bit more than I gave. Hopefully it will help.

```
# Define model
def design_flexiNN(m_type, neurons, shape_timestep, shape_feature, activation, kernel_ini):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(neurons, input_dim=shape_feature, activation = activation, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer=kernel_ini))
    model.add(Dense(1, use_bias=True))
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='Adam')
return model

# fit model
def fit_flexiNN(m_type, train_X, train_y, epochs, batch_size, test_X, test_y):  
    history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=callbacks_list, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=0, shuffle=False)

Earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')

callbacks_list = [Earlystop]

model = design_flexiNN(m_type, neurons, neurons_step, train_X_feature_shape, activation, kernel_ini);

history = fit_flexiNN(m_type, train_X, train_y, ini_epochs, batch_size, test_X, test_y)
```

I've been able to infer the selected epoch by doing `len(history.history['val_loss'])` minus 1, but that doesn't work if you have a `patience` above zero.

Comment: Can you provide the full code of your model ?

Comment: @JonathanDEKHTIAR I added more code. The full code is over 500 lines long! I don't know if what I added will help though. I think I need to use another type of callback. It should be a pretty easy thing to do to just save the selected epoch to a variable, no?

Answer (score 0):

Been trying to solve this myself and realised that the `len(history.history['val_loss'])` method is almost correct. All you need to add is:

`len(history.history['val_loss']) - patience`

which should give you the epoch number for the selected model (assuming that the model didnt run for the full number of epochs).

A slightly more thorough method would be:

```
model_loss = history.history["val_loss"]

epoch_chosen = model_loss.index(min(model_loss)) +1
print(epoch_chosen)
```

Hope this helps!